# APN authentication detection method

Tags: authentication, gprs, ppp, apn, pdp

I am working on a project involving GPRS. In particular I use u-blox Lisa-U200 GPRS/GSM chip. Ran into a problem with the PDP contexts when I started testing it out with different carriers. And after spending days on Google I don't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Why do some phones/devices require APN Authentication (PAP/CHAP/None) and some don't? Or as I have titled the question - how do mobile devices (smartphones) detect APN Authentication method automatically? Or do they at all?

The way I test it is this - Linux box, running pppd with a chat script. The chat script defines the context (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP", and so on) and starts the connection.

The symptoms - if I don't specify the authentication method in the PDP context explicitly it does not even activate (or LCP negotiation fails in the ppp). From the little I understand about GPRS networks this makes sense - I suppose because the gateway node refuses the context if it does not indicate there will be authentication to follow.

Tested with few operators and here comes the most weird part - some of the operators I tested work ONLY if I set it to either PAP or CHAP (and provide correct username and password). And some work whatever I specify (NOAUTH, wrong user/password, etc).

The ideas I have come up with so far are:

1) Provide option to the user to select authentication type. (Not the approach I am fond of because I prefer the user to enter as little as possible.)

2) If the user has set a username/password for the APN - set the auth method to CHAP (I have noticed most operators support both CHAP and PAP). If not - use None as method. (Sounds reasonable?)

3) Brute force - set to CHAP, activate - watch for error; if failed - set to PAP and activate, etc... (Can't say I am too happy about it)

Please excuse me if I answer a very dumb and common question with a well known answer in the mobile industry or if I am completely off track in my logic here, but I am a software developer and that just doesn't make any sense to me :)

Thanks to anyone who shares some experience and knowledge on the topic!

Comment: Operators are different, so are their access points, and so are their security restrictions. Just like there are some e-mail providers who require SSL encryption and some who don't. I'm currently looking for a similar solution myself (how to find out more or less automagically which APN to use). Guess that's why most providers offer config messages...

Comment: That's a very old question and I have already forgotten how things went down in the end. I think we provided option to the user to configure it manually. Didn't like the config messages much either - you don't know if they will be sent, if they will follow some standard format, etc. Probably there is an approach, just didn't figure it out.

Comment: I've ended up with a giant lookup table. With a remotely useful language for that purpose, you can pre-sort by country code, which makes the search tree quite convenient. :)